# Are python int's architecture specific?

Tags: python, binary, integer, cpu-architecture, twos-complement

We can define variables as integer values, e.g.

```
x = 3
y = -2
```

and then operate on bits with binary operators `&`, `|`, `^` and `~`. The question is if we always get the same result on every architecture, or is the behavior architecture specific?
Can we always assume a two's complement representation of integers?

Comment: Any programming languages data types for integers must depend on architecture, more exactly the address bus width.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp A programming language's data types don't have to match the data types provided by the architecture.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: that's not true. For example in Java, `int` is always the same size and same behaviour regardless of architecture. It's up to the Java implementer to ensure that the JVM behaves correctly even if that's not the most efficient size for the architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the python 2 [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) (emphasis mine):

> Plain integers: These represent numbers in the range -2147483648 through 2147483647. **(The range may be larger on machines with a larger natural word size, but not smaller.)** When the result of an operation would fall outside this range, the result **is normally returned** as a long integer (**in some cases**, the exception OverflowError is raised instead). For the purpose of shift and mask operations, integers **are assumed to have a binary, 2’s complement notation using 32 or more bits**, and hiding no bits from the user (i.e., all 4294967296 different bit patterns correspond to different values).

So yes: the integers are architecture specific for Python 2.

From the Python 3 [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Plain integers: These represent numbers in an unlimited range, subject to available (virtual) memory only. For the purpose of shift and mask operations, a binary representation is assumed, and negative numbers are represented in a variant of 2’s complement which gives the illusion of an infinite string of sign bits extending to the left.

So no: the integers are not architecture specific for Python 3.

Comment: The only thing that's architecture specific is whether the returned type is `int` or `long`. The value will be the same either way. And even this distinction doesn't exist in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 5):

Python 2.x supports two integer types: `int` and `long`. `int` is based on the underlying C long type and `long` is an arbitrary precision type. Very early version of Python (pre-2.2), treated the types as two separate types but they were mostly combined in Python 2.2.
Python 3.x only uses the arbitrary precision type.

Bit operations behave as if applied to arbitrary-precision 2's complement numbers. If required, an `int` will be automatically promoted to a `long` in Python 2.x.

The behavior is consistent across platforms.